# How to check android in-app purchase subscription valid or expired in backend PHP API

Tags: php, android, mysql, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I need to check subscription in the **cross-platform**, So I have to check in-app purchase in **PHP**

I can check **IOS in-app purchase subscription** using **iTunes APIs**

But I don't know how to check **android in-app purchase subscription**

can anybody tell me what is the better way to check in-app purchase cross-platform using PHP?

Thank you

Comment: Is https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get able to solve your case?

Comment: Have you got the solution? I have got the same problem. API authentication is not clear for me for Google API-s.

Comment: @EndreOlah not exactly, but this library is really helpful to figure out 1.https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client 2.https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator

Comment: @Hanrui  https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get is not able to solve this case, thank you

Comment: I could get it work with my Google account, so I can go forward with it so far, but I would like to have a service to service authentication and this seems to be a bit more difficult. It involves having the access token request via a JWT token creation, but not clear what should be the content of that encoded message.

Comment: I think you can create a service account inside API Access of Play Console: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account And then use your service account to call the Developer API to get the latest states of each subscription. And you might also want to set up your backend to handle RTDN (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn).